centering the bottom row of subplots in a matplotlib grid
If I have 5 plots I want to present, is it possible to have them in 2 rows, with the top row having 3 plots, the bottom row having 2 plots, but the bottom row centred?
I can plot them with 3 on the top and 2 on the bottom, but I can't work out how to centre the bottom row.
for example:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(10,5), sharey=True)

for i in range(5):
    row,col = divmod(i,3)
    axs[row,col].plot([0, 1], [0, i])
    
fig.delaxes(axs[1,2])

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

gives me this plot:

but i can't work out how to centre the bottom row.
I tried using gridspec, and creating a 2x1 grid, and then putting the top row in the top cell of the master grid, and the bottom row in the bottom cell, but that just stretched the bottom plots out so they took up the whole bottom row. Is it possible to keep all the plots the same size, but centre the bottom two?

and if you try with a GridSpec with 2 rows and 6 cols? In the first row you have axes that are two grids wide, on the second,  you skip the first box, then two axes 2-grids wide and you skip the last.

Since Matplotlib v3.3 you can use subplot_mosaic
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create a mosaic where each plot is two entries wide.  Dots represent spaces.
mosaic = """AABBCC
            .DDEE."""

fig, ax_dict = plt.subplot_mosaic(mosaic, figsize=(10,5), sharey=True)

for i, ax in enumerate(ax_dict.values()):
    ax.plot([0, 1], [0, i])
    
# Turn the y-tick labels back on for the first plot of the second row.  This is
# off by default because the plot does not span the first column of the
# underlying GridSpec.
ax_dict['D'].tick_params('y', labelleft=True)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()



Note that subplot_mosaic uses a GridSpec underneath.  If you want to get hold of it for any reason you can do so from any of the axes:
ax.get_subplotspec().get_gridspec()


This is amazing! I ended up coming up with a very hacky gridspec solution, but didn't know about this update to matplotlib at all.. i guess it is time to look into the matplotlib manual and see what else is new..

You have to set up a custom layout using a GridSpec. Allocate 2 virtual columns per top row column to be able to shift the graphs on the last row with potentially a half graph offset.
The rest is just careful computation of the positions:
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

# defining grid and number of plots
rows, cols = 3, 5
n_plots = 12

axs = np.full((rows, cols), None)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 3))
gs = GridSpec(rows, cols*2)

full_rows = n_plots//cols
extra = cols - n_plots % cols

for i in range(n_plots):
    r, c = divmod(i, cols)
    if r < full_rows:
        axs[r, c] = fig.add_subplot(gs[r, 2*c:2*(c+1)], sharey=axs[0, 0] if i else None)
    else:
        axs[r, c] = fig.add_subplot(gs[r, 2*c+extra:2*(c+1)+extra], sharey=axs[0, 0] if i else None)
    if c:
        plt.setp(axs[r, c].get_yticklabels(), visible=False)

# plotting demo
for i in range(n_plots):
    row,col = divmod(i, cols)
    axs[row,col].plot([0, 1], [0, i])
    
fig.tight_layout()    
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.5)

examples
5 plots on a (2, 3) grid:

4 plots on a (2, 3) grid:

12 plots on a (3, 5) grid:

14 plots on a (3, 6) grid:

as a function
def custom_layout(n_plots, cols, fig_kwargs={}):
    import math
    rows = math.ceil(n_plots/cols)
    
    axs = np.full((rows, cols), None)
    fig = plt.figure(**fig_kwargs)
    gs = GridSpec(rows, cols*2)

    full_rows = n_plots//cols
    extra = cols - n_plots % cols

    for i in range(n_plots):
        r, c = divmod(i, cols)
        if r < full_rows:
            axs[r, c] = fig.add_subplot(gs[r, 2*c:2*(c+1)], sharey=axs[0, 0] if i else None)
        else:
            axs[r, c] = fig.add_subplot(gs[r, 2*c+extra:2*(c+1)+extra], sharey=axs[0, 0] if i else None)
        if c:
            plt.setp(axs[r, c].get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
    return fig, axs

fig, axs = custom_layout(n_plots=5, cols=3, fig_kwargs={'figsize': (5, 3)})

for i, ax in enumerate(axs.flat):
    if ax:
        ax.plot([0, 1], [0, i])

